# Java programming (If-else statement)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-studio

I'm creating an app using android studio , it checks the health of the lights. If the lights are not healthy, it will show an alert. So i am wondering on how do i include an if-else statement into it. i already wrote the code for the alert.

[image: Code]

```
import .... 
public class Function extends AppCompatActivity { 
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_function); } 
    public void showAlert(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); myAlert.setMessage("Not all lights are off!") .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
    dialog.dismiss(); } 
    }) .setTitle("Opps") .create(); myAlert.show();}
    }
```

Comment: Instead of image, post the actual code!

Comment: Can you include your code where and how you save status of the light and when do you need to check the status please include that also

Comment: Where in your code would you like to place the if-statement? An if statement can for the most part only be added within a method.

Comment: i am going to extract the light status from a rpi. I hope to do is this , if (lights are healthy), it shows okay. Else(lights are not healthy) , then it will show the alert. How do i include the alert coding into the if-else statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the concept of alert dialog. Try this:

```
if(lights are healthy)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"lights are healthy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
//call your showAlert method here
showAlert();
}
```

And I cant understand why you are passing a parameter view into your method.